# Issue moving image below div with negative margins

Tags: css, positioning, margins

I want to move an image below the div with negative margin. Negative margin for top seems to work ok but the for bottom there seems to be an issue.

[image]

If anyone has suggestions on how to get a fix as like the attached picture then that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, do you have your current code so it can be examined? Thanks :)

Comment: do you have to use negative margin? would translate work for you

Comment: you said it's ok for negative margin top so use it? for sure bottom will not give the same result